# Show that $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n_1s_1 + \dots + n_ks_k =1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers iff there exist
> $s_1, ..., s_k$ in $S$ and $n_1, ...,n_k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n_1s_1 + \dots + n_ks_k =1$.

It can be proved that if $S$ is a nonempty subset of a group $G$ then

$\langle S\rangle=\{s_1^{n_1}s_2^{n_2}\cdots s_k^{n_k}\mid s_i\in S\text{ for }1\leq i\leq k,n_1,\cdots,n_k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

where $\langle S\rangle=\cap_{H\in F}\quad\forall\quad \{H \mid H\leq G,S\subset H\}$ which is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$.

i.e., If $S$ is a subset of a group $G$ then $\langle S\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $S$ (every element of $\langle S\rangle$ can be expressed as a combination under group operation of finitely many elements of the subset $S$).

If the group binary operation is addition then any element is of the form $n_1s_1+\cdots+n_ks_k$

**My Attempt**

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}$ implies, for any $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ we can write

$m=m_1s_1 + ... + m_ks_k$ where $s_i\in S$ and $m_i\in \mathbb{Z}$

But where does the condition $n_1s_1 + ... + n_ks_k =1$ comes in ?

Comment: You've been on this forum for a long time, and should be familiar with the notations $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The subgroup generated by $S$ is all the multiples of the gcd of all elements in $S$. Try to prove it. Then what you wish to prove from the gcd being the minimal linear combinations of these elements.

Comment: @Oria This actually came into my mind as we do in the case of Bezout's identity, but I was thinking it in terms of  $gcd(m_1,\cdots,m_k)|m$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. the multiples of the gcd are exactly linear combinations of the $m_{i}$'s, which are elements of the subgroup generated by $S$. This approach is an overkill for this specific claim, but it highlights the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once $1\in \langle S\rangle$, we can be sure that $S$ generates $\Bbb Z$. Can you see why?

Also, since $1\in\Bbb Z$, if $S$ generates $\Bbb Z$, then there must be a linear combination of elements in $S$ that is equal to $1$.

---

Your confusion might be because you're viewing $\langle S\rangle$ multiplicatively, not additively.

Comment: I understand $S=\{1\}$ is a generating set, as any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $1.n=n$, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$, so obviously any set $S$ which includes $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @SoorajS.

Comment: Oh I think it's as simple as this : $S$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $m=m_1s_1+\cdots+m_ks_k$ where $s_i\in S$ and $m_i$ are integers. Since $1\in \mathbb{Z}$ there must be integers $n_i$ such that $1=n_1s_1+\cdots+n_ks_k$, right ?

Comment: Exactly, @SoorajS :)